# Harded Coded Java List in Java Class

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I am conducting some testing on a list item for object Student however i prefer to create a hard coded list in the java class object and just pull the data from there rather than connect to the database and select records in a result set. However it's been very long time since i did this and i think i am not writing up the class accurately.

I would like every time i call this class or instantiate it that i get back the hard coded list. Under is the class. I need some assistance in setting up the hard coded list.

**Student Class**

```
public class Student {

    private int studentId;
    private String studentLastname;
    private String studentFirstName;
    private int studentAge;


    public Student() {

    }
    public Student(int studentId, String studentLastname,
            String studentFirstName, int studentAge) {

        this.studentId = studentId;
        this.studentLastname = studentLastname;
        this.studentFirstName = studentFirstName;
        this.studentAge = studentAge;
    }
    public int getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }
    public void setStudentId(int studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }
    public String getStudentLastname() {
        return studentLastname;
    }
    public void setStudentLastname(String studentLastname) {
        this.studentLastname = studentLastname;
    }
    public String getStudentFirstName() {
        return studentFirstName;
    }
    public void setStudentFirstName(String studentFirstName) {
        this.studentFirstName = studentFirstName;
    }
    public int getStudentAge() {
        return studentAge;
    }
    public void setStudentAge(int studentAge) {
        this.studentAge = studentAge;
    }


}
```

**Data**

**I would like to insert the following data**

```
 Student.add(1, "john","william", 20);
 Student.add(2, "bob","elis", 25);
 Student.add(3, "harry","potter", 19);
 Student.add(4, "micheal","louis", 20);
 Student.add(5, "smith","sobers", 30);
```

Comment: Could you provide some more data about that list you are hardcoding?

Comment: I also do not understand exactly what kind of list you are talking about. Do you mean a list of students?

Comment: @ederollora i included the data

Comment: @SharpKnight yes a list of students

Comment: Your post indicates that you haven't even attempted it. Please show us your attempt, if you have, and let us know where your problem is.

Comment: @BheshGurung i do not know how to structure the hard coded list and thats the issue i am having

Comment: You probably want to create an object that acts as repository, e.g. `StudentRepositoy`. Make it singleton, add a field for the list, a method for initialization, and populate the list in there with your `Student` instances. I don't think it's a good idea to keep all that in the `Student` class itself. Is that what you were thinking about?

Comment: I added in my code the loop to take back all student objects in case you needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many options for this. One could even recommend to use a dependency injection framework do specify a particular implementation of a "source of students". However, in the simplest case, it could look like one of these methods...

```
class StudentUtils
{
    public static List<Student> getDummyList(int n)
    {
        List<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        { 
            list.add(new Student(i, "Last"+i, "First"+i, 20+(i%10)));
        }
        return list;
    }

    public static List<Student> getDummyList()
    {
        List<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();
        list.add(new Student(0, "Foo", "Bar", 20));
        list.add(new Student(1, "Fee", "Bur", 30));
        list.add(new Student(2, "Faa", "Bir", 40));
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: i used the second example you gave

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to understand it, let's see if my code helps you:

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{

  Student std;

  ArrayList<Student> aSt = new ArrayList<Student>();

  aSt.add(new Student(1, "john","william", 20));
  aSt.add(new Student(2, "bob","elis", 25));
  aSt.add(new Student(3, "harry","potter", 19));
  aSt.add(new Student(4, "micheal","louis", 20));
  aSt.add(new Student(5, "smith","sobers", 30));

        // to get back each Student object
  for(int i = 0; i < aSt.size(); i++){

    std = aSt.get(i);

    //now tou can print a var..
    System.out.println("The age of "+std.getStudentFirstName()+" is "+std.getStudentAge());

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
public ArrayList<Student> loadStaticData()
{
   ArrayList<Student>  StudentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
   StudentList.add( new Student(1,"aaaa","aaaa",25));

   StudentList.add( new Student(2,"bbba","bbaa",25));

return StudentList;
 }
```

And call this,

```
ArrayList<Student>  list = loadStaticData();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing, but let me see if I can help based on what I think you are saying.

```
i prefer to create a hard coded list in the java class object
```

I think you are saying that you would like to maintain a variable that represents a list to hold Student information, perhaps something like this:

```
private ArrayList<Student> myList = new ArrayList<Student>;
```

In this case you would add Student objects to the list after they are instantiated.